# Read the number of columns using awk/sed

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have the following test file

```
Kmax Event File - Text Format
1 4 1000 
65 4121 9426 12312 
56 4118 8882 12307 
1273 4188 8217 12309 
1291 4204 8233 12308 
1329 4170 8225 12303 
1341 4135 8207 12306 
63 4108 8904 12300 
60 4106 8897 12307 
731 4108 8192 12306 
...
ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ
```

In this file I want to delete the first two lines and apply some mathematical calculations. For instance each column `i` will be `$i-(i-1)*number`. A script that does this is the following

```
#!/bin/bash

if test $1 ; then
   if [ -f $1.evnt ] ; then
      rm -f $1.dat
      sed -n '2p' $1.evnt | (read v1 v2 v3
      for filename in $1*.evnt ; do
         echo -e "Processing file $filename"
         sed '$d' < $filename > $1_tmp
         sed -i '/Kmax/d' $1_tmp
         sed -i '/^'"$v1"' '"$v2"' /d' $1_tmp
         cat $1_tmp >> $1.dat
      done
      v3=`wc -l $1.dat | awk '{print $1}' `
      echo -e "$v1 $v2 $v3" > .$1.dat
      rm -f $1_tmp)
   else
      echo -e "\a!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
      echo -e "  Event file $1.evnt doesn't exist  !!!!!!"
      echo -e "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
   fi   
else
   echo -e "\a!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
   echo -e "!!!!!  Give name for event files  !!!!!"
   echo -e "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
fi
awk '{print $1, $2-4096, $3-(2*4096), $4-(3*4096)}' $1.dat >$1_Processed.dat
rm -f $1.dat
exit 0
```

The file won't always have 4 columns. Is there a way to read the number of columns, print this number and apply those calculations?

**EDIT** The idea is to have an input file (*.evnt), convert it to `*.dat` or any other ascii file(it doesn't matter really) which will only include the number in columns and then apply the calculation `$i=$i-(i-1)*number`. In addition it will keep the number of columns in a variable, that will be called in another program. For instance in the above file, `number=4096` and a sample output file is the following

```
65 25 1234 24
56 22 690 19
1273 92 25 21
1291 108 41 20
1329 74 33 15
1341 39 15 18
63 12 712 12
60 10 705 19
731 12 0 18
```

while in the console I will get the message `There are 4 detectors`.

Finally a new file_processed.dat will be produced, where file is the initial name of awk's input file.

The way it should be executed is the following

```
./myscript <filename>
```

where `<filename>` is the name without the format. For instance, the files will have the format `filename.evnt` so it should be executed using

```
./myscript filename
```

Comment: all of the above could be done in one brief, simple awk script. If you show us your expected output given the sample input file you posted, we can help you. I posted an answer as a first guess at what you're trying to do - take a look and let us know if it's correct and, if not, what it needs to do differently.

Comment: OK, check my editted answer and add a comment below that answer if it needs to do anything different.

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with this to see if it's close to what you're trying to do:

```
$ numdet=$( awk -v num=4096 '
    NR>2 && NF>1 {
        out = FILENAME "_processed.dat"
        for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
            $i = $i-(i-1)*num
        }
        nf = NF
        print > out
    }
    END {
        printf "There are %d detectors\n", nf | "cat>&2"
        print nf
    }
    ' file )

There are 4 detectors

$ cat file_processed.dat
65 25 1234 24
56 22 690 19
1273 92 25 21
1291 108 41 20
1329 74 33 15
1341 39 15 18
63 12 712 12
60 10 705 19
731 12 0 18

$ echo "$numdet"
4
```

Is that it?

Comment: It does the job! Let me understand, though...You set `numdet` to be a variable that does all that? In addition I am running it and I get `./myscript: line 14: $: command not found`. Note that the file to be processed, is there!

Comment: No, the awk script does all that and then prints the number 4 which is then saved in the shall variable `numdet`. Are you by any chance including the leading `$ ` in `$ numdet=$( awk...`? If so, don't - `$ ` is my prompt.

Comment: Ah I see in your script you're using the old `\`...\`` construct to invoke commands (e.g. `v3=\`wc -l $1.dat\``). That syntax has been deprecated, these days you should be using `$(...)` instead (e.g. `v3=$(wc -l $1.dat)`). Maybe that clarifies how my script is executing an awk command and saving its stdout in the shell variable `numdet` just like you were saving the stdout of `wc` in the shell variable `v3`.

Comment: You were right! I included `$`...Silly me... The thing is that the message `There are ...` is in the output file and not in the console.

Comment: Yes because you specifically stated you wanted that in your question: `a sample output file is the following...There are 4 detectors`. If that's not what you actually want then just remove or edit the obvious line of code that does that - `printf "There are %d detectors\n",nf > out`. If you can't figure out how to get the script to do what you want, update your question to clarify what it is you really want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk

```
awk 'NR<=2{next}{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=$i-(i-1)*4096}1' file
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I am trying to print the number of fields. I am using `END{print "There are %d detectors", NF}` but it gives me `There are %d detectors1`. So I need the correct number of fields and a way to print it.

Comment: @Thanos - use `printf`, not `print` for formatted output.